# What rights can I delegate to other users on Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

As an employer on Stack Overflow Careers, there is a "Manage Users" tab under the "my account" page.  It seems you can invite other people to join your account as either an Administrator or a Member.

This sounds great, because for any given job I might have two or three people in my company participating in the job search.  I might also have multiple job postings, and want multiple people to be reviewing potential candidates.

But in practice, it seems that a job listing or a candidate search subscription can only belong to one person.  I can change the owner, but that doesn't help with collaboration.

Alas, it seems the only way to achieve true collaboration in hiring is by sharing a password to a single account.  Is this by design?  Surely there is a better way.

What *exactly* can a "member" or an "administrator" do then?

Comment: Didn't it change name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Company Accounts is a new feature that you've stumbled upon.  First off, you're correct that only one person can own a product (job listing or search subscription).  The current functionality of Company Accounts allows you (or any administrator) to move a product from one person in the company to another.  But that doesn't help you with collaboration.

Phase 2 of Company Accounts will be launching this week and does allow collaboration on the of editing job listings.  What this means is that any owner of a listing (regardless of whether they are a Company Admin or Member) can "share" their listing with someone in the company.  Sharing allows non-owners editing abilities on the job listing.  It does NOT mean dual ownership. The job owner is still the only person who will receive email notifications for applications.  The sharee is simply receiving editing rights.

Now for Admins and Members.  There are several differences:

1. Admins can invite new users to a company account.  Members cannot.
2. Admins can move products (ie change ownership) between any user in the Company Account.  Members cannot.
3. Admins can expel users from a company account.  Members cannot.
4. Admins can view any members (and other Admins) reports in the new "Reporting" section of My Account.  They can also view aggregate company reports on all Job Listings, Search Subscriptions, and coming soon Company Pages and Company Page Ads.
5. Admins can view all ordering history across the organization.
6. Members will have the ability to share products they currently own, but will not have visibility into other user's products (via Reporting) or the ability to affect the distribution of products as mentioned above.

The Company Account feature as a whole is still incomplete.   Every week we're tweaking and adding new features to make organizations lives easier on Careers 2.0.  One of the many goals for this feature is to eliminate the need for you or anyone in the company to share a PW or merge accounts in order to get what you want out of the product.  We're getting closer...

Comment: Thanks for the details.  In our particular scenario, the company purchased a candidate search subscription.  A HR/recruiting person is responsible for searching, but has no way to share those candidate profiles with the actual hiring managers.  Buying separate subscriptions for the hiring managers is too costly, so we're kinda stuck.

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes, this is tougher than job listings and is not slated for release this week.  It is one of the next features we'll be working on integrating better in company accounts.  For now, there is an imperfect option where your HR person can share candidates or lists of candidates from the "Candidates" tab of the search product.   This generates an email with links to each candidate's profile that can be sent to your hiring managers.  Not perfect by any means, but a short term solution.